# Change Datasource of a chartsheet (no embedded sheet)

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I have a dataset with is quite simple. When I add data at the end of it, I want to automatically get that in my chartsheet.

For example:

At this moment, the chartsheet exists with a Datasource "A1:Q10". After I enter some values within the sheet where the Datascource is, it should change to A1:R10.

But it doens't work. Here the code which ends up in

> "Application or object-defined error"

```
Sheets("_Chartsheet-sheet").Select
Activesheet.Chartobjects(1).Activate
ActiveChart.SetSourceDate Source:=Range("A10:" & ActualLetter & "10")
```

Comment: Do you need to prefix a10:xyz10 with a sheet name like `sheet1!a10:z10`?

Comment: i did it as well with "Source: Worksheet("_xyz_").Range("A1......") - didnt work neither

Comment: For starters, `SetSourceDate` isn't a valid method. Did you mean: `SetSourceData` ?

Comment: These kinds of mistakes can be avoided by always putting this as the first line in every module: **`Option Explicit`** This forces you to properly declare and refer to objects, variable, properties, etc.

Comment: Does fixing the typo alone fix the problem?

Comment: The "SetSourceDatE" was a Typo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [ashleedawg noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49366482/change-datasource-of-a-chartsheet-no-embedded-sheet#comment85734182_49366482), `SetSourceDate` isn't a member of the `Chart` class - using `Option Explicit` and the VBE's *IntelliSense* & auto-complete will help prevent these. Writing it off as a typo, there's another problem with the code...

```
Source:=Range("A10:" & ActualLetter & "10")
```

`Range` being unqualified, if that code is written in a standard code module, it implicitly refers to whatever the `ActiveSheet` is - in this case...

```
Sheets("_Chartsheet-sheet").Select
```

...a chart sheet, which isn't a `Worksheet` and, as such, doesn't have a `Range` property.

An unqualified `Range` call, made explicit, reads as follows:

```
[_Global].Range("address")
```

The solution is to properly qualify that `Range` call with the `Worksheet` object instance you mean to work with - assuming `Sheet1`:

```
Source:=Sheet1.Range("address")
```

That `Sheet1` is a global-scope `Worksheet` object that you get for free, given that your worksheet exists at compile-time. Select the worksheet under "Microsoft Excel Objects" in the VBE's *Project Explorer*, then look at its properties (F4): you'll notice it has a `Name` property with a value that corresponds to its "tab name" (the name you'd use to fetch the worksheet by name), but it also has a `(Name)` property, with a value that corresponds to its "code name" - that's the identifier VBA uses to generate the free global-scope object variable you can (and *should*) use anywhere in your code whenever you need to refer to that worksheet.

Fetching that object from the `Sheets` or `Worksheets` collection by name, puts your code at risk: unless workbook structure is protected, the user can change that "tab name" at any time, and that will break every `Worksheets("name")` call in your code.

If the code is written in a worksheet's code-behind, then the unqualified `Range` call is implicitly referring to that worksheet. In that case, explicitly qualifying `Range` with `Me` would make the code more... explicit about its intent.

Lastly, `.Select` and `.Activate` aren't needed here. [**Avoid Select and Activate**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba), it's macro-recorder code that's as frail as code gets. Instead, work the object references - here I'm assuming that the code is written in the source sheet's code-behind, hence the `Me` qualifier in front of `Range`:

```
Dim chartSheet As Chart
Set chartSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("_Chartsheet-sheet")
chartSheet.SetSourceData Source:=Me.Range("A10:" & ActualLetter & "10")
```

Comment: Sorry for taking so long. Had a little incident. It worked! Thank you so much. Really lovely explained and on a very good level.